# Variation of Lagrangian with respect to components of inverse of metric tensor

Tags: tensors, variational-calculus

I am super new to Mathematica, so I apologize if the question is trivial.
I have defined metric tensor (4x4 matrix), inverse metric and Lagrangian:

```
n := 4
coord := {t, x, y, z}

metric := {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, Exp[2 alpha[t] - 4 sigma[t]], 0, 0}, {0,
0, Exp[2 alpha[t] + 2 sigma[t]], 0}, {0, 0, 0,Exp[2 alpha[t] + 2 sigma[t]]}}

inversemetric := Inverse[metric]

lagr := -1/2 Sum[
Sum[inversemetric[[Mu, Nu]] D[phi[t], coord[[Mu]]] D[phi[t], 
   coord[[Nu]]], {Mu, 1, n}], {Nu, 1, n}] - pot[phi, chi]
```

Now I want to derive components of stress-energy tensor, which is done by varying the Lagrangian. I was trying to use `<<VariationalMethods` but I get all the components equal to 0:

```
tener := Table[-2/(metdet) VariationalD[metdet*lagr, 
inversemetric[[Mu, Nu]][t], {t}], {Mu, 1, n}, {Nu, 1, n}]
```

where `metdet := Sqrt[-Det[metric]]`

Written in mathematical language it should be:
$$
T_{\mu\nu}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{-\det(g)}}\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}(\sqrt{-\det(g)}L)
$$
where g is metric, g with upper indices are components of inverse metric and L is the Lagrangian.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In most definitions like yours, use `=` [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of `:=` [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html). Typically, `SetDelayed` is used to define functions. For example, `f[x_] :=  x^2`, then `f[3]` returns `9`.